# How to stop MVC 4 ajax application from redirecting to LogIn.Aspx

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

For our new application we are switching from MVC 3 to MVC 4. We are using Ajax to fetch most content from the server
In MVC 3 we had the following in the web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms

            defaultUrl="Home/Index"
            protection ="All"
            slidingExpiration="true"
        />
    </authentication>
```

If the user hit an [Authorize] attribute the ajax call would fail with an 'Unauthorized' error.

```
    $.getJSON(
            url,function (data) {processAjaxCallResult(data);}
       )
       .fail(
             function (xhr, status, error)
             { handleAjaxCallError(xhr, status, error); }
       )
       .done(
             function () {completedAjaxCall();}
       );
```

The 'handleAjaxCallError' will then pickup the error, and make sure the user is directed to correct MVC action to login

In the new MVC 4 with the same web.config the application tries to go to login.aspx. Which is not part of the application. The redirect of server to this non existing page causes the client to stop working with an internal server error, breaking the app

How do I get my 'unauthorized' error back?

**Update**

Following Josh's advise I added an override of HandleUnauthorizedRequest like so:

```
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if ((context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers)["X-Requested-With"] ==
            "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
     }
```

this results in a "Forbidden" error which I can handle much like I did the 401 in the old situation.
However setting a 401 **still** results in the redirect to the non-existing login page.

Well for now I got my application back on track so Josh here are my points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own authorize attribute that inherits from the AuthorizeAttribute class:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

In it, you could override the HandleUnauthroziedRequest:

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext){
    // Return to JSON instead of following the authenticate route
}
```

It requires a bit of work on your part to use the custom attribute but allows you to completely customize the authorization process.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Not quite sure yet how "// Return to JSON instead of following the authenticate route" is going to pan out. Plus 1 for now